# delegated jwt token for microsoft graph api working only for my resources

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-files

I'm following the microsoft documentation to acquire a user token:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

1. I create an Azure AD Application and authorize several apis.
2. I generate the consent url and it returns an authorization code.
3. From this code, I request an Access token.

So far so good.
Then I use the user access token and use it to make some Microsoft graph api calls. It is still working fine (I'm accessing Microsoft teams resources).

In a channel,there is a message that I have created and in which have copy/pasted an image.
(The html content shows that the image has been stored into my personal onedrive.)
I can read the image and download it programmatically.
The problem happens when a colleague creates a message that contain an image that he copied / pasted in the message.
The image points to his personal onedrive, and when I try to download it using  the token, I'm getting an unauthorized exception.
Of course, if I use the url in a web browser, I can access the file.
It looks like the token does not allow me to navigate to a sharepoint site or to a file in another onedrive that I have access to.

What permission should I exactly request?

Repro:

Azure AD application permissions:
[image]

The consent URL: I have requested various different scopes, it has no impact on the result.
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantName/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=clientI&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&response_mode=query&scope=Files.ReadWrite.All%20Chat.Read%20ChatMessage.Read&state=31:5&prompt=consent

JWT token:
[image]

URL That I try to download programmatically and that generates the unauthorized
https://tenantName-my.sharepoint.com/personal/the valid colleague/Documents/Microsoft%20Teams%20Chat%20Files/managerapi_logs.txt

When I paste this url in a web browser I can access the file.

The code for the download function:

```
private async Task Download(string url, string fileName)
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _token);
        var respons = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (respons.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var downloadStream = await respons.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            _oneDriveUpload.UploadToOneDrive(fileName, downloadStream, "Teams");
        }
        else
        { 
            // It fails here with unauthorized
            throw new Exception(respons.ReasonPhrase);
        }
    }
```

and finally a proof that my token works for files that I own and that are stored in my onedrive.
All of them have been accessed succesfully. But as soon as I jump out of my onedrive, I'm getting the exception.
[image]

Comment: @tiny wang: I have explained that I have access to the file. If I copy the link in a webbrowser, I can access it.

Comment: the question is : why does my token not permit to access a file that I have access to?

Comment: sorry I ignored it, and I can't answer your question..

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with the token generated.
It did not allow to access shared resources in Onedrives or Sharepoint sites.
For this I had to use an application token and it was mandatory to get the token using clientId AND certicate, not clientId AND secret.